# xml resources or sqlite

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite

i am making an android application that will use a database. the user won't be able to edit the database, the database will be static most of the times, but i will need to update the database frequently for future releases. It will only contain 1 table but with hundreds or even thousands data.
Which one should i use so that it will be efficient and effective memory-wise ? XML or SQLite ?
Any help will be very appreciated.

P.S. I have read [Raw resources versus SQLite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213550/raw-resources-versus-sqlite-database) but i decide to make a new question rather than replying to an old question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for Sqlite always , File Processing is Costlier than Sqlite. And also Sqlite will be more secure than XML. The Thing that you are trying , I had been gone these kind of issues. There I started with File but at one point of time , FILE IO was making my app very slow because of huge data processing. to Overcome that Issues I used Sqlite. As a result , My app became 10 times faster !

Comment: Thanks ! I think i will go for sqlite

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to work with alot of data i would recommend SQLite.

It will allow you to update or alter the database when your app is released without erasing any current information from the user's phone they have in the app.(Very beneficial)

It will also be good for querying with a cursor and pulling information fast.

I would recommend this!